# Row polymorphism in Haskell: trouble writing Forth DSL with "transformations"

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, higher-order-functions, concatenative-language, impredicativetypes

I've been inspired by the recent Haskell blog activity<sup>1</sup> to try my hand at writing a Forth-like DSL in Haskell. The approach I have taken is simultaneously straightforward and confusing:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, RankNTypes, ImpredicativeTypes #-}

-- a :~> b represents a "stack transformation"
--          from stack type "a" to stack type "b"
-- a :> b represents a "stack" where the top element is of type "b"
--          and the "rest" of the stack has type "a"
type s :~> s' = forall r. s -> (s' -> r) -> r
data a :> b = a :> b deriving Show
infixl 4 :>
```

For doing simple things, this works quite nicely:

```
start :: (() -> r) -> r
start f = f ()

end :: (() :> a) -> a
end (() :> a) = a

stack x f = f x
runF s = s end
_1 = liftS0 1
neg = liftS1 negate
add = liftS2 (+)

-- aka "push"
liftS0 :: a -> (s :~> (s :> a))
liftS0 a s = stack $ s :> a

liftS1 :: (a -> b) -> ((s :> a) :~> (s :> b))
liftS1 f (s :> a) = stack $ s :> f a

liftS2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> ((s :> a :> b) :~> (s :> c))
liftS2 f (s :> a :> b) = stack $ s :> f a b
```

Simple functions can trivially be transformed into their corresponding stack transformations. Some playing around yields pleasant results so far:

```
ghci> runF $ start _1 _1 neg add
0
```

**The trouble comes when I try to extend this with higher-order functions.**

```
-- this requires ImpredicativeTypes...not really sure what that means
-- also this implementation seems way too simple to be correct
-- though it does typecheck. I arrived at this after pouring over types
-- and finally eta-reducing the (s' -> r) function argument out of the equation
-- call (a :> f) h = f a h
call :: (s :> (s :~> s')) :~> s'
call (a :> f) = f a
```

`call` is supposed to transform a stack of the form `(s :> (s :~> s'))` to the form `s`, by essentially "applying" the transformation (held at the tip of the stack) to the "rest" of it. I imagine it **should** work like this:

```
ghci> runF $ start _1 (liftS0 neg) call
-1
```

But in actuality, it gives me a *huge* type mismatch error. What am I doing wrong? Can the "stack transformation" representation sufficiently handle higher-order functions, or do I need to adjust it?

<sup>1</sup>N.B. Unlike how these guys did it, instead of `start push 1 push 2 add end`, I want it to be `runF $ start (push 1) (push 2) add`, the idea being that maybe later I can work some typeclass magic to make the `push` implicit for certain literals.

- https://github.com/leonidas/codeblog/blob/master/2012/2012-02-17-concatenative-haskell.md
- https://gist.github.com/1847747

Comment: actually, I'd like to get rid of `start` too, and just have `runF $ _1 _1 add`, though I don't really see how that's possible with this setup.

Comment: Impredicate types are a generalization of Rank-n types, which allow a forall inside any type constructor, not just function types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `:~>` type is not what you actually want (hence the `ImpredicativeTypes`). If you just remove type annotation from `call` then your last sample will work as expected. Another way to make it work is to use less fancy but more appropriate type with extra parameter:

```
type Tran s s' r = s -> (s' -> r) -> r

call :: Tran (s :> (Tran s s' r)) s' r
call (a :> f) = f a
```

But if what you are after is a nice DSL syntax and you are can tolerate `OverlappingInstances` then you can even pretty much get rid of liftSx functions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeFamilies,
             FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts,
             UndecidableInstances, IncoherentInstances  #-}

data a :> b = a :> b deriving Show
infixl 4 :>


class Stackable s o r where
    eval :: s -> o -> r


data End = End

instance (r1 ~ s) => Stackable s End r1 where
    eval s End = s


instance (Stackable (s :> a) o r0, r ~ (o -> r0)) => Stackable s a r where
    eval s a = eval (s :> a)

instance (a ~ b, Stackable s c r0, r ~ r0) => Stackable (s :> a) (b -> c) r where
    eval (s :> a) f = eval s (f a)

-- Wrap in Box a function which should be just placed on stack without immediate application
data Box a = Box a

instance (Stackable (s :> a) o r0, r ~ (o -> r0)) => Stackable s (Box a) r where
    eval s (Box a) = eval (s :> a)


runS :: (Stackable () a r) => a -> r
runS a = eval () a

-- tests
t1 = runS 1 negate End
t2 = runS 2 1 negate (+) End

t3 = runS 1 (Box negate) ($) End
t4 = runS [1..5] 0 (Box (+)) foldr End
t5 = runS not True (flip ($)) End

t6 = runS 1 (+) 2 (flip ($)) End
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your type synonym is a polymorphic type

```
type s :~> s' = forall r. s -> (s' -> r) -> r
```

Using a polymorphic type as an argument to a type constructor other than `->` is called "impredicativity". For instance, the following would be an impredicative use

```
Maybe (forall a. a -> a)
```

For various reasons, type inference with impredicativity is hard, that's why GHC complains. (The name "impredicative" comes from logic and the Curry-Howards isomorphism.)

In your case, the solution is simply to use an algebraic data type with a constructor:

```
data s :~> s' = StackArr { runStackArr :: forall r. s -> (s' -> r) -> r}
```

Basically, the explicit constructor `StackArr` supplies enough hints to the type checker.

Alternatively, you can try the `ImpredicativeTypes` language extension.

Comment: The problem with using a data declaration is that it pollutes the desired syntax. The reason the type synonym works nicely is because the transformation *is* a function, and these functions can be chained together by function application *as if* it were function composition. I did try `ImpredicativeTypes`, which allows the `call` to be well-typed, but using `call` as desired is impossible; there's something inherently wrong with the type I gave it. I think the problem is that the typechecker can't understand the "function application" going on at the type level.